# Set-Location does not update $local:PSScriptRoot

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to update `$local:PSScriptRoot`?

In my scripts I am using `$local:PSScriptRoot`, and I expected it to be updated when `Set-Location` changes the location.

```
Set-Location "./subfolder"
$local:PSScriptRoot
```

expected:

```
<$local:PSScriptRoot>/subfolder"
```

Do you know how to update `$local:PSScriptRoot` or if there is a better practice for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$psScriptRoot` is not a variable whose value may be changed; it is automatically set at script invocation to the full path of the location of the script file that you are interrogating it from.  That is, if the script file you are executing is `/usr/local/scripts/pscore/get-data.ps1`, the value of `$psScriptRoot` will be set to `/usr/local/scripts/pscore`, even if you use `Set-Location` to set the current working directory to something else, and you will not be able to change it.

Answer (score 1):

As [Jeff Zeitlin explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57804522/1630171), the [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-3.0) `$PSScriptRoot` is automatically set to the location of a script upon invocation of that script.

What you are actually looking for is a different automatic variable: `$PWD` (PWD stands for "Print Working Directory"), or more specifically its `Path` property (`$PWD.Path`). The working directory is what you change with the `Set-Location` cmdlet.

Comment: Thanks for this; I wasn't aware of `$PWD`; if I needed it, I'd have probably used an inline `(Get-Location)`.